# 2.5 inch HDD enclosure with jumper pins?

Tags: hard-disk, drive-enclosure

So I have an old HP laptop which died years ago. I removed the 2.5 Seagate HDD and wanting to use it as external hdd.

However I am confused as to what type of enclosure should be used.

Fyi I have little knowledge in hdd and all that stuff, so I found out there are 4 'jumper pins' .

The problem is when I browse the available enclosure they only have the SATA connectors and the jumper pins doesn't seem to connect anywhere. At least from my perception

I just wanna make sure before buying
Is this okay/supposed to be this way?

Thanks in advance

*Im using stackexchange app and it doesn't allow me to post images, I dont know why
But the HDD is 320GB Seagate Momentus 5400.6

Comment: From what I can tell, you should be fine to purchase any enclosure that is SATA compatible.That connection you refer to, I'm unsure of, but shouldn't be a factor at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is supposed to be this way.**

Those jumper pins are not used to be connected to *something*. Instead, you use *jumper shunts* to connect the pins together. A jumper shunt, by the way, is this thing that you can see on many motherboards, or on all old IDE hard disk drives:

[image]

The goal is to be able to specify a bunch of options, such as slowing the transfer rate down, or, in the case of IDE drives, it was used to distinguish between the master and the slave. The exact use of those jumpers depends on the manufacturer and the model. In the case of Seagate Momentus 5400.6:

> If the host system does not support SATA 3Gb/s operation, place a jumper on pins 1 and 2 to limit the drive to 1.5Gb/s operation.

<sup>Source: [PDF manual](https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/5400.6%20(Wyatt)/100528359e.pdf), page 32.</sup>

It doesn't tell what would happen if you put a jumper shunt on pins 2 and 3, or 3 and 4, or put two jumpers together.

Notice that the manual tells explicitly on page 2 that:

> It is not normally necessary to set any jumpers or other configuration options.

Therefore, just use an ordinary enclosure, connecting SATA *and* power.

Comment: Thanks for sparing your time to answer the question and explain the details. I think I can understand your explanation. Again, thank you and have a good day.